# divide every item in an array of arrays in one shot

Tags: python, logging, numpy

I have an numpy aray of shape 3X4X4 as shown:

```
[[[0 0 0 2]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 0]
  [0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
```

I want to divide every number in each 4 X4 matrix  inside my array by 0.25. 
Then I want to take a log of all those values. ( therefore Im dividing all the values in each array by .25 then taking the log of that number)
The output should be the same 3x4x4 matrix, just the values are changed.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do:

```
numpy.log(yourNumpyArray / 0.25)
```

And numpy will do the right thing (divide each element by 0.25)

**Read more:**

- [Basic Operations - Tentative Numpy Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5)

Comment: From the premature micro optimization department, `np.log(yourNumpyArray) - np.log(0.25)` gives the same result, but replaces expensive divisions by cheap subtractions. It is roughly 10% faster on my system.

Comment: @Jaime weird, in my system it was kind of the opposite: `>>> %timeit np.log(a / 0.25)` gave `100000 loops, best of 3: 8.99 µs per loop` and 
`>>> %timeit np.log(a) - np.log(0.25)` resulted in:
`100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop` (a tiny bit slower)

Comment: I ran it on a big (1000x1000) array. With few items, as in the OP's question, the extra call to `np.log` probably eats up all the improvement. On my system the crossover happens for ~800 items in the array.

Comment: @Jaime that's it, then, I tested with exactly the OP's input. Thanks for sharing. =)

Answer (score 3):

I dont see what is wrong with this

```
>> import numpy as np
>> a = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 2],[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 1, 1, 0]] ,[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0] ,[0, 0, 1, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0]]])
>> a
[[[0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]

>> np.log(a/0.25)

array([[[       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,  2.07944154],
        [       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf],
        [ 1.38629436,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf],
        [       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf]],

       [[       -inf,  1.38629436,        -inf,        -inf],
        [       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf],
        [       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf],
        [       -inf,  1.38629436,  1.38629436,        -inf]],

       [[       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf],
        [       -inf,  1.38629436,  1.38629436,        -inf],
        [       -inf,        -inf,  1.38629436,        -inf],
        [       -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 2],[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 1, 1, 0]] ,[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0] ,[0, 0, 1, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0]]])
arr /= 0.25
arr = np.log(arr)
```