# How can I divide elements in a list in an efficient way using python/numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, data-analysis

I am trying to divide all elements in a list by two (or multiply the elements by 0.5). Each time I try this I get a TypeError saying I cannot divide the elements. Then, I tried converting my list into a numpy array and multiplying by a scalar vector, but I reached a similar error. How can I take all the elements in either a list or array and divide them by two? Thanks!

[image: See code here]

Comment: Please post your code as text

Comment: Please read [ask] as well as learn how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying values in a list individually in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082053/multiplying-values-in-a-list-individually-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [divide every item in an array of arrays in one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037830/divide-every-item-in-an-array-of-arrays-in-one-shot)

Answer (score 0):

Your series has string types in it:

```
# clean the column
qb["Passes Completed"] = qb["Passes Completed"].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == "--" else x).astype(np.float)

# do the division operation
qb["Passes Completed"] / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
a=a/2
Outputs: array([0.5,1,1.5,2])
```

In this link you can find more information: http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html

If you want to search more on this topic just google numpy array operations.